# How to apply textures with alpha channel?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, compositing-nodes

I am doing the [Introduction to Camera Tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY) tutorial by Blender Guru and at some point he is applying a texture to create cracks in the road (around the hole, see image below).

[image]

As you can see there are no cracks visible in this image. I think the problem is that I don't know how to apply textures with an alpha channel ? But perhaps it has to with the node tree in the compositor. Blender Guru is working with Blender Render, I use Cycles.

Who can help ? Blend file with texture packed attached.

P.S I know there is also an issue with the floor but I think I can only ask one question

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the ground that you are trying to apply the texture to is on the Background layer and is being used as a sort of a mask, so it is not being rendered.  What I did to fix your problem is duplicate the ground, move the duplicate in the Z direction just slightly to avoid it intersecting with your ground that is being used as a mask, and then move the duplicated ground onto the foreground layer, which you have defined as the first layer, by pressing <kbd>M</kbd>.
[image]

Now the ground will render.  Next, you need to apply the cracks as a texture to the new ground.  Applying textures with alpha channels is simple using cycles.  Here is the node setup that is used:

[image]

Now if you render your should be able to see the cracks.

[image]\

[image]