# Background is not blending well

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, tracking, masking, shadows

In the [Introduction to Camera Tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY) tutorial by Blender Guru, in the first 40 minutes, he gives an introduction to Camera Tracking and then shows how to make a hole in a road. He did this in Blender Render, but I'm trying to do this in Cycles. Somehow, I made a few mistakes because this is my rendered image.

[image]

Notice how there is a huge shadow where my mask is. Any thoughts on what I can do better?

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: It's your nodes for the plane. They are not optimized for Cycles. I'm writing up an answer now.

Comment: ohhh.... supers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the problem is caused by your nodes for the plane. In BI, your plane rendered white with black cracks. In Cycles, you rendered black with white cracks, I believe. Also, your *UV Mapping* needed some touching up, as only part of the cracks image was actually showing. After fixing your nodes and the *UV Mapping*, I achieved the following result.

[image]

The following is the modified node setup for your plane mask. I used the *Emission* and *Light Path > Is Camera Ray* nodes to achieve the *Shadeless* effect provided in BI (logic from [Import Images as Planes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images) addon Cycles node setup). Then, I used the *Alpha* output of the cracks *Image Texture* to differentiate between white, normal, and cracks, black. I used the *Alpha* instead of the *Color* with *Bright/Contrast* to make a *Fac:* because in this case, there was a readily available *B/W Fac:* already.

[image]

Here is the .blend file. Note that I may have messed up several of your paths.

[image]

As an alternate solution, you can use the following compositing. Note the changes in the two nodes immediately following the mask's *RenderLayer* node. If you do this, do not utilize the above solution as well. I will say that this works slightly worse, but it's still reasonable.

[image]

Comment: I did post the problem with the cracks as a separate question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60687/how-to-apply-textures-with-alpha-channel I will now study both answers and try to come to an understanding :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @OldMan Ok, I didn't see it. All I did was scale down the map until there were no cracks showing in the hole in the center. Then I just moved it around a bit to center the cracks better. Lastly, I rotated the map so that the cracks appeared facing towards the camera. I did all of this while in rendered view, so I could see my results.

Comment: no problem at all. I am very glad that you dive into this problem and learn me things :) Only reason that I mentioned that other question is that it might give you second thoughts.

Comment: maybe off-topic, but ... do you simply know an awful lot or do you have a gift to analyse new problems and come up with completely new answers (also for you) ? I am simply interested how you came up with this answer because this is really very unexpected answer for me (never heard of Light Paths)

Comment: your solution clearly works very well, but I have this "feeling" that to apply the texture with alpha channel like showed in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60687/how-to-apply-textures-with-alpha-channel (but without duplicating the circle object) should also work somehow ... but I cannot get it figured out

Comment: @OldMan I'm not sure I have a gift, but I was never taught Blender; everything I learned I learned from Google, so I have a lot of practice asking the right questions. Plus, I have a good memory, so things stick.

Comment: @OldMan I didn't duplicate the mask, so I must have done something right. I did do this tutorial myself long ago (all in BI, though) but I believe my method, since it both shows the cracks and eliminates the weird shadows, should render the other one that you linked to obsolete. If you use my .blend file in the above post, you should not need the answer from the other post.

Comment: As I said, your answer works and is very clear (even I understand it haha). So yes I accept your answer happily. I also think I should learn to aks the right (at least better) questions

Comment: @OldMan Just added an alternate solution. It works slightly worse, but it's also simpler.