# Create a plane that renders nothing behind it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shadows, lighting

I'm kinda following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY&t=2447s), but using cycles instead of *blender internal*. Because I'm using cycles, I had to manually set up the nodes and render layers. This image is what i'm supposed to have currently (from the tutorial):

[image]

And this is what the render result is for me:
[image]

I have transparency checked. This is my node setup and render layers:

[image][image][image]

And these are my layers:

Layer 1: [image]
Layer 2: [image]

[image]

Comment: [This question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/60734/2217) should help you.

Answer (score 3):

Give the plane a holdout material. This should make it block everything behind it and yet be completely transparent.

I will try to update the answer with screenshots soon.