# correct cycles node arrangement

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

Good Afternoon! anyone have any suggestions on the correct node arrangement here? I've tried a couple but nothing is working. Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is how it is supposed to look. this pic is from Noesis, a program used for viewing and exporting game .DATs[image]

here is the unrendered view in blender
[image]

here is the rendered view, and wherein the problem lies. I appreciate the help my friends!
[image]

EDIT: here is the .blend and textures
https://mega.nz/#F!zaxGCaCa!d09bEVsqxvSnL9_AoRMZSw

Comment: It looks like you may be missing a texture in your material. Is is possible there is more than one image that should be used here? The black and white wall material looks like the kind of image that would be used to control the transition between to materials.

Comment: perhaps. now that you mention it i looked through my textures and couldn't even find the one with bricks on it. How can that be though if the bricks show up in the unrendered view?

Comment: When you focus on the transition from the brick wall to the white wall you will notice, that in the original game engine, there is specks of white paint over the brick wall, in the blender engine there is only brick and only white, and in the cycles render there is only the white specks visible. I strongly suspect, that your texture image has a lot more channels than you expect it to have. If you could share the texture file it would probably be possible to devise a node setup that extracts all channels properly and let's you render the scene correctly

Comment: appreciate the help, i admit nodes are challenging to me. files are up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exporter you are using, seems to have some problems:

First the alpha-channel for the texture with the bricks is wrong. The alpha channel with the bricks is set to transparent whereas it should be opaque.

[image: Texture with alpha channel]
While this could be controlled with a node setup, the bigger flaw is that the wall consist of two meshes, each with a plane occupying the same space which leads to z-fighting -

[image: Z-fighting]

leading to artefacts in the final render.

[image: Render artefacts]

To get to the final render I set up the nodes for alpha channel in cycles like explained in "[How to apply textures with alpha channel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60687/how-to-apply-textures-with-alpha-channel)"

The problem with z-fighting is described [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/cycles-transparent-object-causes-z-fighting-artefacts/644706).

If you need to get this to work, I suggest, you clean up the geometry of the wall (remove the overlapping part, probably needs a fix for the UV-mapping as well) and set up the nodes with transparency to account for the alpha-channel, while excluding the brick texture.